# Stop Location Listener in Android

Tags: android, gps, android-location, locationlistener

In my android app I need to get current GPS location of the user at the start of the application only if location has change from the previous location. But the problem is when I inside the application if location change (*ie* If user was traveling while using the app) app is starting from the beginning.

I need to stop location listener after getting user current location. removeUpdates method didn't work for me.

Please help me on this issue.
thanks in advance !

Comment: removeUpdates is the way to go, can you show some code as to why it did not work.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
mLocManager.removeUpdates(locationListenerObject);
mLocManager = null;
```

Call this inside your `onLocationChange` Method when lat and long has been captured by the listener.

Hope I helped..

Comment: It might take some time for the onLocationChange method to be called. Around 1 sec might be. Right?

Comment: thx this works. the weird thing is that the .removeUpdates() wants us to ask for permissions!

Answer (score 6):

You can stop the LocationListener by making its object to null after stoping LocationListener `locationManager.removeUpdates(mLocListener);`, that is `mLocListener = null;` when you want it to stop fetching the Latitudes and Longitudes.

Comment: I just tried this on a actual device and it does not remove the listening for updates

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is setting the listener to null necessary if we already called `removeUpdates(locationListener l)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop continuous location updating by calling method `locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener)`.

Here is an example :

```
LocationManager locationManager; 
LocationListener locationListener;

// for location updates 
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

// stop location updating
locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(String provider, LocationListener listener, Looper looper);
```

If you only need to get the current location once, try this method instead using

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(String provider, long minTimeMs, float minDistanceM, LocationListener listener)
```

and stop the update using `locationManager.removeUpdates(LocationListener listener)`

hope this works and help others with same problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
locationManager = activity!!.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

locationListener = object : LocationListener {
            override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                if (location != null) {
                    Log.e(
                        "LOCATION",
                        "Latitude " + location.latitude.toString() + "  | Longitude :" + location.longitude.toString()
                    )
                    if (locationListener != null)
                        locationManager!!.removeUpdates(locationListener!!)
                }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),location.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {
            }

            override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {
            }

            override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {
            }
        }
```