# Android :How to get Current Location in Longitude and latitude?

Tags: android, gps, location, locationlistener, on-location-changed

I want to store current Location to database when i click on `Button`.

The location is stored but it is receiving 0.0 ,0.0  don't know where's the mistake is in my code Here i post my complete code for this please help me out from this.

**getting current location**

```
GetCurrentGPSLocation gps = new GetCurrentGPSLocation(getActivity());

            // check if GPS enabled
            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                // \n is for new line
                lat.setText( ""+latitude);
                longi.setText("" +longitude);
                latitude12=lat.getText().toString();
                longitude12=longi.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                longi.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                lat.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }
```

**GetCurrentGPSLocation**

```
    package com.example.sachin.omcom;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

public class GetCurrentGPSLocation extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {


    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    // flag for GPS status
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location; // location
    double latitude; // latitude
    double longitude; // longitude

    // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

    // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GetCurrentGPSLocation(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("Network", "Network");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                        Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener
     * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
     * */
    public void stopUsingGPS(){
        if(locationManager != null){
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GetCurrentGPSLocation.this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     * */
    public double getLatitude(){
        if(location != null){
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        // return latitude
        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     * */
    public double getLongitude(){
        if(location != null){
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        // return longitude
        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     * @return boolean
     * */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
     * */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

  //  @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }}
```

Comment: Have you added permission for location service in manifest file ???

Comment: yes i added the permission

Comment: Okay then let me go through your code and get back to you, also make sure that if you are running your app on marshmallow then you have to ask for runtime permission

Comment: Extend `Service` instead of `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)

Comment: Just extend your current class with Service and implement LocationListener to get updated location and you are good to go

Comment: @Bhavnik whats the problem with `extending AppCompatActivity` ?  why you suggest a service ..`extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener` works well

Comment: when i am using Service it gives me error like Error:(213, 5) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: You're using some severely broken GPS code.  Check out the reason its broken and some working code at http://gabesechansoftware.com/location-tracking/   In particular canGetLocation is implemented wrong.  It doesn't tell you if a location is available, just if GPS isn't turned off by the user.

Comment: @Sachin Solanki try my example

Comment: @Charuka m trying..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-on-a)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onLocationChanged` gets called every time when your location updates , so keep & update a global value and take that value on your `Button` click to do what you want

```
 private LatLng latLng;

       @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location!=null){
         latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()); }
    }
```

or based on time or distance you can get the location as well use `android.location.LocationListener()` see Edit for that,

If you want to manually call `onLocationChanged` after a time period even the location is not changed  use below

```
 LocationRequest  mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000); //5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(30000); //3 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    //mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(0.1F); //1/10 meter

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

---

**Edit** : This is the location listener you can use this separately without the above if you want

```
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private android.location.LocationListener myLocationListener;

    public void checkLocation() {

        String serviceString = Context.LOCATION_SERVICE;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(serviceString);


        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }


        myLocationListener = new android.location.LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location locationListener) {

                if (isGPSEnabled(YourActivityName.this)) {
                    if (locationListener != null) {
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivityName.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(YourActivityName.this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            return;
                        }

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } else if (isInternetConnected(YourActivityName.this)) {
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }



            }

            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }

            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }
        }; 

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1, myLocationListener); 
}
```

**isInternetConnected method**

```
public static boolean isInternetConnected(Context ctx) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityMgr = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo wifi = connectivityMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        NetworkInfo mobile = connectivityMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        // Check if wifi or mobile network is available or not. If any of them is
        // available or connected then it will return true, otherwise false;
        if (wifi != null) {
            if (wifi.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (mobile != null) {
            if (mobile.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**isGpsEnabled method**

```
  public boolean isGPSEnabled(Context mContext) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        return locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
```

**Note** : Now do not get confuse. There are 3 ways mentioned here.

1.use `onLocationChanged` automatically

2. use `onLocationChanged` manually
3. use `android.location.LocationListener()` added the full implementation (this will not help you to learn but to get a data. Go through these lines and understand them by searching what happen actually )

Comment: @Sachin Solanki  see understand the logic.first learn when on `onLocationChanged` gets called , then put a log or a sout and see does that work.. okay.. Then you know that method gets called when location changes.

Comment: you already have `onLocationChanged` method. okay.. now imagine you want to call that `onLocationChanged` manually lets say after each 3 seconds..now use that below method..  `Private LocationRequest  mLocationRequest,` --< this is a var,

Comment: then use the other part  in a method starting from `mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000); //5 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(30000); //3 seconds
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
   ......` in a method and call it from `onCreate`

Comment: Thanks.. m sure it gonna help me i'm trying the third method .. but i want like when i click on Button at that time only location is generate and store in database so what should i put code in onClickListner?

Comment: if you want that ..call that method .. so it will listen for locations ..may be u can add that call in oncreate. Keep a global value and update it with new location.when the button is clicked get that global value.now you dont need listner work any more. so in your onclick get the location if location is not null .. then stop the listner.. here is how to stop it.only 2 lines http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894234/stop-location-listener-in-android

Answer (score 1):

1.Add dependency in build.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
```

2.Add those 3 permissions in manifest file

```
 android.permission.INTERNET,ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
```

3.How you should write your class `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager locationManager;
    String provider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Check Permissions Now
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                    0);
        }
        // Getting LocationManager object
        statusCheck();

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(
                Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating an empty criteria object
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the provider that meets the criteria
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);

        if (provider != null && !provider.equals("")) {
            if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
                final Intent poke = new Intent();
                poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                        "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
                poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
                poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
                sendBroadcast(poke);
            }
            // Get the location from the given provider
            Location location = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 500, 0, this);

            if (location != null)
                onLocationChanged(location);
            else
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
            if (location != null)
                onLocationChanged(location);
            else

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location can't be retrieved",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Provider Found",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void statusCheck() {
        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(
                Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            buildAlertMessageNoGps();

        }
    }

    private void buildAlertMessageNoGps() {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(
                "Your GPS seems to be disabled, do you want to enable it?")
                .setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                    final int id) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(
                                        android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                            final int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
        final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        /* getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu); */
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Getting reference to TextView tv_longitude
        TextView tvLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);

        // Getting reference to TextView tv_latitude
        TextView tvLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);

        // Setting Current Longitude
        tvLongitude.setText("Longitude:" + location.getLongitude());

        // Setting Current Latitude
        tvLatitude.setText("Latitude:" + location.getLatitude());
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Check Permissions Now
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                    0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

4.How you should write your `activity_main.xml`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_location"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/str_tv_location"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_longitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_location"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_latitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/tv_longitude"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```